# In need of assistance with a specific question finding critical points

Tags: calculus

**Here's the problem I've been given:**

Determine all critical points for the following function:  $\ f(x) = 2x^2 + {256 \over x} $

**What I've done so far:**

1. Find the derivative of $\ f(x) $.  This is equal to $\ 4x - {256 \over x^2} $
2. Determine points at which $\ f'(x) $ equals zero or is undefined.  I get two numbers:  $\ f'(x) $ equals zero when $\ x = 4 $ and is undefined when $\ x = 0 $.  These are the critical points I get for $\ f(x) $.  However, the course I am taking says that there is only one critical point at $\ x = 4 $.

What am I doing incorrect?  Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Garren

Comment: Yes, there is only one critical point, because the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\{0\}$

Comment: As @BijeshK.S said the domain of $f(x)$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Then we dont need to consider what happen for $f'(x)$ at zero.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)  just go through the definition

Comment: Thanks guys.  Having a "duh" moment LOL.